# How to know whether I have a accelerometer on my phone?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am building an Android app on my phone that uses accelerometers to detect shakes. However, `onSensorChanged` is never called when I shook my phone. This means that it cannot detect any shakes! I suspect that I don't even have a accelerometer on my phone!

My phone is Sony Xperia C5303 running Android 4.3. How can I know whether an accelerometer is present on my device?

Comment: use the service menu

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you're asking for a programmatical way to find out about the presence of the sensors in question, or a personal service to download the technical specification of your device, or an app recommendation.

Comment: I mean just in any ways, to find out if I have an accelerometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the sensors on a device you have to create an instance of the *SensorManager* class and pass the SENSOR_SERVICE argument. For example:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Then, for example you can get a listing of every sensor on the device by calling the *getSensorList()* method with TYPE_ALL. For example:

```
List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

If you want to list the accelerometers then you need to use TYPE_ACCELEROMETER  instead of TYPE_ALL.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)